# Fees when requesting an upgrade

Tags: fees-and-charges, klm, upgrades

I booked my parents premium economy seats with KLM as the prices were really expensive 5 months ago for business.   Now I have seen the prices drop and I contacted the airline to see if I could change the booking and pay the difference in costs, but they want to add on $800 in charges.  Is there anyway around this?
Many thanks

Comment: What do the T&C of your original booking say about fees for changes?

Comment: A 250 pounds per person charge for changing the booking, but we want the same dates and route, just a better seat

Comment: Changing to a better seat, even on the same dates and routes, is _changing the booking_.

Comment: Do you have miles which could be used for the upgrade? It’s usually a lot more cost effective. Have you checked the cost of cancelling + rebooking? Also note that some countries add a substantial tax to flights in some classes, so in those cases even if the airline does not charge anything extra themselves there can be a hefty price difference.

Comment: What about trying to book a class upgrade. If the prices are going down, they should offer it (possibly just in the weeks before the flight). Check on KLM site, on your the ticket/options dashboard.

Comment: Is that $800 for upgrading a return flight booking, or just one leg? If you’re prepared to wait until the last minute, you could try for a [paid upgrade while checking in online or at the airport](https://www.klm.co.uk/information/manage-booking/upgrades), which might work out cheaper than doing it in advance but of course with the risk that there is no availability.

Comment: Thanks, I am happy to pay  the $1200 difference in costs, but not the extra $800 in charges.  I do have points so that is an option and can see about an upgrade when we check them in.  Thanks for your help!